# Python Dictionary String Replacement

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is there anyway to replace a key in a dictionary to a more accurate key description?

```
JIRA_BASIC_TYPE_MAP = {
"string": str,
"number": int,
"customfield_10000": str }
```

I want to change `"customfield_1000"` to `MailList: str`. How would I replace the key to this in Python? I have to use "customfield_1000" for the dictionary. I know you can just do `MailList = "customfield_1000"` and then do `MailList: str` but how would I do this in a dictionary? How would I declare variable in a dictionary?

TLDR: how to give a more descriptive key instead of just doing this?

`"customfield_10000": str #This is mail_list variable`

I want this.

```
mail_list: str #inside mail_list = "customfield_10000", so easier to read code
```

Comment: Can you add more details regarding what you want to achieve? The end goal

Comment: I have edited my end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [walrus operator feature in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) like this:

```py
JIRA_BASIC_TYPE_MAP = {
  'string': str,
  'number': int,
  (MailList := 'customfield_10000'): str,
}
```

Note that, as pointed out in the link, the best practice is to

> Try to limit use of the walrus operator to clean cases that reduce complexity and improve readability.

so use this feature with care. Also, as per the [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it's preferred to use the snake case name `mail_list` or something similar for the `MailList` variable, as the latter seems to be a class.